# Pass array of objects to style prop in React and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In JavaScript React I would do this to "merge" several styles:

```
const customStyle= {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
};

<p 
    style={[{fontStyle: 'italic'}, customStyle]}>
    {Some Text....}
</p>
```

However, when I try this in a TypeScript React project I get the following:

```
TS2322: Type '({ fontWeight: string; } | { fontStyle: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
   Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
     Type '{ <S extends { fontWeight: string; } | { fontStyle: string; }>(predicate: (value: { fontWeight: string; } | { fontStyle: string; }, index: number, array: ({ fontWeight: string; } | { fontStyle: string; })[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: { ...; } | { ...; }, index: number, array: ({ ...; } ...' is not assignable to type 'Filter | undefined'.
```

This array construct comes in quite handy, because the order of the elements is important. With `customStyle` I could overwrite everything I defined in the object `{fontStyle: 'italic'}` before...

How would I pass several styles to the `style` prop of an HTML element?

Comment: I've never seen that being used. Do you have a page that describes this usage?

Comment: @vera. I am doing that in React-Native all the time. Here is one online example doing it https://www.newline.co/30-days-of-react-native/day-04-styles#applying-multiple-styles. I assumed that this is also possible in React. But apparently, its not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use spread operators?
like this:

```
style={{fontStyle: 'italic', ...customStyle}}
```

your styles will be also overwritten in this way

Answer (score 1):

you'd need to reduce your array to a single object:

```
style={[{fontStyle: 'italic'}, customStyle].reduce((carry, current) => ({ ...carry, ...current}), {})}
```